# java library which enables composing futures (flatMap) asynchronously

Tags: java, java-8, future

I thought that new java 8 CompletableFuture would be able to execute async tasks, one after another without blocking threads, using "thenComposeAsync" method.

I think this is not the case. A thread waits synchronously for the task to be completed (CompletableFuture.java:616  r = fr.waitingGet(false);)

And the following piece of code never executes "task 3" if nThreads <= 2:

```
int nThreads= 2;
Executor e= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> {
    System.out.println("task 1 threadId " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}, e).thenComposeAsync( (Void v1) -> {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> {
        System.out.println("task 2 threadId " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }, e).thenComposeAsync((Void v2) -> {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> {
            System.out.println("task 3 threadId " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }, e);
    }, e);
}, e).join();
System.out.println("finished");
```

¿what other java library should I use? I want that code to execute in one thread (with nThreads = 1).

Comment: Why not just start one new thread and execute the tasks normally within it, if you want to run them one after another?

Comment: It is to make the application more responsive (reactive). The application may have thousands of parallel executions. It is not efficient to have thousands of threads running.Each task will consume some little cpu, stop and wait for some seconds to complete when an event arrives.

Comment: I haven't tried the Future extensions in JDK 8 yet, but you can find some smart stuff in the Guava library (ListenableFuture) or if you need a higher level of abstraction have a look at RxJava (Observables).

Comment: @user3531959 You said `one after another`, though. If you create a thread separate from the UI thread and execute the tasks normally (one after another) inside it, you won't block the UI thread.

Comment: I'll give guava a try.

Comment: Phillip, I need each task execution to be asynchronous (not blocking)(otherwise I'd have too many threads). 

I mean the following: let a "work" be composed of N tasks wich must be executed one after another. I'll have thousands of works executing in parallel. Each work will have 10 tasks average. Each task will consume some cpu and sleep for 5 seconds average waiting for a completion event.

One thread per work is too much load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use CompletableFuture.thenComposeAsync()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571250/how-to-use-completablefuture-thencomposeasync)

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine with `thenComposeAsync` if you use a `ForkJoinPool` as `ExecutorService` instead:

```
final ExecutorService e = new ForkJoinPool(nThreads);
```

Also, be sure to shut down the service at the end (otherwise the program will not exit):

```
e.shutdown();
```

Edit: perhaps some more explanation: 
if you draw the dependency graph including the tasks due to `thenComposeAsync`, which have to finish before their successors can run (because they supply the return value that is passed to their successors), you will find that you need more than two threads to execute the graph with an adversary scheduler.

Generally, it is difficult to predict how many threads minimum are needed to execute a dynamically created task graph.  `ForkJoinPool` acknowledges that by trying to stay within the given parallelism level, but creates additional threads if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working. Instead of CompletableFuture.thenComposeAsync, I call:

```
static public <T,U> CompletableFuture<U> thenComposeAsyncNoWait(CompletableFuture<T> first, Function<? super T, ? extends CompletableFuture<U>> fn, Executor executor) {
    CompletableFuture<U> ret= new CompletableFuture<>();
    first.handleAsync( (T t, Throwable e) -> {
        if ( e != null )
            ret.completeExceptionally(e);
        else
            fn.apply(t).handleAsync( (U u, Throwable e2) -> {
                if ( e2 != null )
                    ret.completeExceptionally(e2);
                else
                    ret.complete(u);
                return null;
            }, executor);
        return null;
    }, executor);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using thenApply it seems to work

```
    int nThreads= 1;
    ExecutorService e= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

    System.out.println("starting");
    CompletableFuture<Integer> compFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
        System.out.println("task "+42+" threadId " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return 42;
    }, e).thenApplyAsync(i -> {
        System.out.println("task "+i+" threadId " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return i+1;
    }, e).thenApplyAsync(i -> {
        System.out.println("task "+i+" threadId " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return i+1;
    }, e);


    compFuture.join();
    e.shutdown();
    e.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("finished");
```

Comment: With "thenApply" it works but method signature is different to "thenComposeAsync". I need the second one.

Programming with threads:
  void play(String file) { ... }
  thread: play("file1.wav"); play("file2.wav");

With "fibers" (light threads)
  CompletableFuture<Void> play(String file) { ... }

Comment: Your example runs into thread starvation because of how you built up the dependencies. I count two "thens" and so three runnables, the first ends up waiting on your last one (even though you use *Async), which can't execute because you ran out of threads. I don't understand why you "need" the second one. chaining three runAsync's runs fine on one thread. How are your tasks dependant?

Comment: @user3531959 thenCompose is executed with the completionStage as parameter, what suggests me that you would need at least one thread  per thenCompose plus the initial one. ThenApply just receives the result of the CompletionStage as parameter, and, therefore, it doesn't need any extra thread to run (it will reuse the one that executed the previous stage)