# How to use CompletableFuture.thenComposeAsync()?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, future

Given:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int nThreads = 1;
        Executor e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
        {
            System.out.println("Task 1. Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }, e).thenComposeAsync((Void unused) ->
        {
            return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
            {
                System.out.println("Task 2. Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }, e);
        }, e).join();
        System.out.println("finished");
    }
}
```

I am expecting a single executor thread to run task 1, followed by task 2. Instead, the code hangs if `nThreads` is less than 2.

1. Please explain why the code hangs. I can see it is blocked in [CompletableFuture:616](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#616) waiting for some `Future` to complete, but it's not clear why.
2. If I allow the use of 2 threads, what is each thread being used for?

In short, please help me understand how `thenComposeAsync()` actually works. The Javadoc looks like it was written for robots instead of human beings :)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't use blocking operations in tasks (here join()) in tasks executed on thread pools, especially on fixed thread pools. Allow blocking only on independent threads.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, that's a good point but in the above example `join()` is executed outside the task, isn't it?

Comment: In JDK 8u5 - 8u31 author's code hangs, but in JDK 8u40+ code prints two thread IDs (equal) and "finished" (same for JDK 11, 15). Seems like this particular case/issue has been "fixed".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The `thenComposeAsync` method places a new task for your executor that grabs the single thread and waits for your `Task 2` to complete. But this one has no more threads to run. You can instead use `thenCompose` method that executes in the same thread as `Task 1` to avoid the deadlock.
2. One thread is executing `Task 1` and `Task 2` and the second one is taking care of composing the results of the two.

Note: `CompletableFuture`(s) work best with a `ForkJoinPool` that is more efficient in processing tasks that spawn new tasks. The default `ForkJoinPool` was added in Java 8 for this purpose and is used by default if you don't specify an executor to run your tasks.

Here is a good presentation about where these new features shines and how they work: [Reactive Programming Patterns with Java 8 Futures](https://wn.com/reactive_programming_patterns_with_java_8_futures).

Comment: The link to the presentation is broken. Is [this](https://wn.com/reactive_programming_patterns_with_java_8_futures) a replacement?

Answer (score 6):

It blocks on `runAsync` that's inside `thenComposeAsync`.  `thenComposeAsync` runs the supplied function in a thread inside executor e.  But the function you gave it tries itself to execute the body of runAsync inside the same executor.

You can see better what's going on by adding another trace output:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println("Task 1. Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}, e).thenComposeAsync((Void unused) -> {
    System.out.println("Task 1 1/2. Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Task 2. Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }, e);
}, e).join();
```

Now if you run it with a 2-thread executor, you will see that Task 1 1/2 and Task 2 run on different threads.

The way to fix it is to replace `thenComposeAsync` with just regular `thenCompose`.  I am not sure why you would ever use `thenComposeAsync`.  If you have a method that returns a `CompletableFuture`, presumably that method doesn't block and doesn't need to be run asynchronously.

Comment: `I am not sure why you would ever use thenComposeAsync. If you have a method that returns a CompletableFuture, presumably that method doesn't block and doesn't need to be run asynchronously.` That's a very good point.