# Why does thenComposeAsync await the return to be redeemable

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have written up a contrived code example, and it might not be code that someone ought to use, but I believe it **should** work.  However it instead deadlocks.  I've read the answers described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571250/how-to-use-completablefuture-thencomposeasync), but found them insufficient.

Here is the code example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        
        int nThreads = 1;
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( nThreads );
        

        
        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)
            .thenComposeAsync((unused)->{
            
                System.err.println("About to enqueue task");
                CompletableFuture<Boolean> innerFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
                executor.execute(() -> {

                    // pretend this is some really expensive computation done asynchronously

                    System.err.println("Inner task");
                    innerFuture.complete(true);
                });
                System.err.println("Task enqueued");
                             
                return innerFuture;
            }, executor).get();

        System.err.println("All done");
        System.exit(0);

    }
    
}
```

This prints:

> About to enqueue task
>
> Task enqueued

And then it hangs.  It's deadlocked because the executor only has a single thread, and it's waiting for the innerFuture to become redeemable.  Why does "thenComposeAsync" block for its return value to become redeemable, instead of returning the still-incomplete future and freeing up its thread in the executor?

This feels completely unintuitive, and the javadocs don't really help.  Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how CompletionStages work?  Or is this a bug in the implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after a lot of interesting conversation, I decided to email one of the JDK authors.  Found out that this behavior wasn't intended, and is indeed a bug present in 1.8u25.  There is a fix that will be released with a later patch version of Java 8.  I don't know which.  For anyone wanting to test the new behavior, you can download the latest jsr166 jar here:

http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/index.html

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  This should be long since fixed by now though.  Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: I thought I was, but it turned out to be an unrelated bug in user code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

First, let me rewrite your code with 2 static functions to make it easier to see what's going on:

```
// Make an executor equivalent to Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)
// that will trace to standard error when a task begins or ends
static ExecutorService loggingExecutor(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
            0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()) {

                @Override
                protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
                    System.err.println("Executor beginning task on thread: " 
                       + t.getName());
                }

                @Override
                protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
                    System.err.println("Executor finishing task on thread: "
                       + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

            };
}
```

And

```
// same as what you pass to thenComposeAsync
static Function<Boolean, CompletableFuture<Boolean>> inner(Executor executor) {
    return b -> {
        System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                   + ": About to enqueue task");
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> innerFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        executor.execute(() -> {
            System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                   + ": Inner task");
            innerFuture.complete(true);
        });
        System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                   + ": Task enqueued");

        return innerFuture;
    };
}
```

Now we can write your test case as follows:

```
ExecutorService e = loggingExecutor(1);

CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)
        .thenComposeAsync(inner(e), e)
        .join();

e.shutdown();

/* Output before deadlock:
Executor beginning task on thread: pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-1: About to enqueue task
pool-1-thread-1: Task enqueued
*/
```

Let's test your conclusion that the first thread is not released until the result of the second future is computed:

```
ExecutorService e = loggingExecutor(2);  // use 2 threads this time

CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)
        .thenComposeAsync(inner(e), e)
        .join();

e.shutdown();

/*
Executor beginning task on thread: pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-1: About to enqueue task
pool-1-thread-1: Task enqueued
Executor beginning task on thread: pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-2: Inner task
Executor finishing task on thread: pool-1-thread-2
Executor finishing task on thread: pool-1-thread-1
*/
```

Indeed, it appears that thread 1 is held until thread 2 is done

Let's see if you are right that `thenComposeAsync` itself blocks:

```
ExecutorService e = loggingExecutor(1);

CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = 
        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)
        .thenComposeAsync(inner(e), e);

System.err.println("thenComposeAsync returned");

future.join();

e.shutdown();

/*
thenComposeAsync returned
Executor beginning task on thread: pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-1: About to enqueue task
pool-1-thread-1: Task enqueued
*/
```

`thenComposeAsync` didn't block.  It returned the `CompletableFuture` right away and the deadlock only occurred when we tried to complete it.  So what should it take to complete the future returned by `.thenComposeAsync(inner(e), e)`?

1. The API needs to wait for innner(e) to return `CompletableFuture<Boolean>`
2. it needs to wait for the returned `CompletableFuture<Boolean>` to also complete.  Only then is the future complete.  So, as you can see, it cannot do what you suggest and return the incomplete Future.

Is it a bug?  Why does the CompletionStage hold on to thread 1 while the inner task is being computed?  It is not a bug becuase, as you noted, the documentation is pretty vague and doesn't promise to release threads in any particular order.  Also, note that Thread1 will be used for any subsequent `then*()` methods of CompletableFuture.  Consider the following:

```
ExecutorService e = loggingExecutor(2);

CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)
        .thenComposeAsync(inner(e), e)
        .thenRun(() -> System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                         + ": All done"))
        .join();

e.shutdown();

/*
Executor beginning task on thread: pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-1: About to enqueue task
pool-1-thread-1: Task enqueued
Executor beginning task on thread: pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-2: Inner task
Executor finishing task on thread: pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-1: All done
Executor finishing task on thread: pool-1-thread-1
*/
```

As you can see, .thenRun(...) got executed on thread 1.  I believe this is consistent with other *Async(... , Executor exec) methods of CompletableFuture.

But what if you want to split up the functionality of `thenComposeAsync` into 2 separately controllable steps instead of leaving it up to the API to juggle threads?  You can just do this:

```
ExecutorService e = loggingExecutor(1);

completedFuture(true)
        .thenApplyAsync(inner(e), e) // do the async part first
        .thenCompose(x -> x)         // compose separately
        .thenRun(() -> System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + ": All done"))
        .join();

e.shutdown();
```

Everything will run nicely on 1 thread with no deadlocks.

In conclusion, is this behavior of unintuitive as you say?  I don't know.  I cannot imagine why `thenComposeAsync` even exists.  If a method returns `CompletableFuture`, it shouldn't block and there should be no reason to call it asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks Misha for the detail and the effort.  Your example is far clearer than mine.  I need to wrap my head around a couple of your statements.  Specifically: "1.  The API needs to wait for innner(e) to return CompletableFuture<Boolean>; 2.  it needs to wait for the returned CompletableFuture<Boolean> to also complete. Only then is the future complete. So, as you can see, it cannot do what you suggest and return the incomplete Future."  I'm not making the mental leap implied by "as you can see..."  I'll think about this a bit then post back here when I grok it better.